# Wicket path-style parameters

Tags: java, url, wicket

I want to make some site, is should have user profiles accessible under URL like
site.com/user/m4ks
I have no idea how to make this using Wicket. Its possible to make BookMarkablePage with any *wildcards* or so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mount an [`IRequestTargetUrlCodingStrategy`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/IRequestTargetUrlCodingStrategy.html) to achieve this. My suggestion would be [`MixedParamHybridUrlCodingStrategy`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/MixedParamHybridUrlCodingStrategy.html). There you can define an array of known parameter names that will be appended to the URL like this: `mypage/param1/value1/param2/value2`, while other unknown parameters will be appended like this `mypage?param3=value3`.

Anyway, here's a [tutorial page on how to mount Bookmarkable pages and use UrlCodingStrategies](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/url-coding-strategies.html).

Answer (score 2):

Look at URL Coding strategies. They are explained in the [wicket wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/url-coding-strategies.html). You are looking for the 'IndexedParamUrlCodingStrategy'. Javadoc is [here](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/index.html?org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/IndexedParamUrlCodingStrategy.html).

Edit:
Damn you Sean, you where faster.. ;)